# Why does counting down an unsigned int loop forever in C?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

The below code runs in an infinte loop. 
'i' has been intialised with the value 1 and then compared with 0.

So printf() stmt should execute once but it runs infinetly.

```
unsigned int i = 1;
for (; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("Hello: %u\n",i);
}
```

please explain this behaviour.

Comment: Could you show the rest of your code it may be memory corruption before , or even buffer overflow of one of the function parameters

Comment: @Sergey: I don't think you're right there - it's just a bug.  See the answers.

Comment: your loop condition is waiting for an **unsigned** int to be negative... how can that be *even* possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As other answers said, it's because it's unsigned and all. I will tell you an elegant way to do what you want to do ***with*** an unsigned integer.

```
unsigned int i=10;
while(i --> 0) printf("Hello:%u\n", i+1);
```

This `-->` is referred to sometimes as the ***goes to*** operator. But it's in fact just `--` and `>`. If you change the spacing, you'll get

```
while( i-- > 0 )
```

My2c

Comment: It may occasionally be called that.  But it's a bit of a silly name!  It only "goes" downwards.

Comment: @Oli: Does ***goes down to*** sound better? :)

Comment: Just write it as `(while i-- > 0)` unless your goal is obfuscation.

Comment: @Keith: I don't think `i --> 0` is obfuscated. To be perfectly honest, it is more natural for me than `i-- > 0`

Comment: @Armen: To the unwary teader, it implies that the language has a "-->" operator.

Comment: I agree with Keith here. Though the syntax may look more natural, it  may easily lead people then to write `unsigned int i = 0; while( i --> 10 ) ... `, too.

Comment: This gives different scope to i. If you don't want this use: for(unsigned i=N; i-->0; ) {}

Answer (score 10):

Because `i` is `unsigned` it can't go negative, so `i>=0` is always true.

When `i` is zero and you do `i--`, the value of `i` wraps round to the *maximum* value an `unsigned int` can have (which is greater than zero).

You should use a signed integer, by removing the `unsigned` modifier.

Comment: :Thanks ritchie for making me to understand.

Answer (score 3):

It's an `unsigned int`. Decrementing it from 0 will **not** yield -1.

To achieve your intended goal, you need to drop the `unsigned` qualifier. This will remedy the [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) causing the observed behavior.

Comment: The article you link to correctly states that *for unsigned integers modulo wrapping is the defined behavior and the term overflow never applies: "a computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow."*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Indeed it does.

Answer (score 1):

The standard says for unsigned integers if the result would go below zero you add 2^n where n is the number of bits in the representation.

Since the integer is unsigned, the compiler will optimize this to an infinite loop.

Comment: Optimization has little to do with it.  It's already an infinite loop.

Comment: I mean it removes the condition check.

Comment: Ok -- but it's not required to do so,

Comment: Are you agreeing or disagreeing?

Answer (score 1):

By defining the `i` as `unsigned int` you have made it a always non-negative integer therefore all the possible values `i` can have are all positive integers (in its range) and 0. Therefore the condition in the loop is always true as `i` is always either greater than or equal to `0` therefore it runs infinitely.